# Import event from ics into Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, calendar

I use Outlook web client, https://outlook.office.com/calendar, opened in a web browser (Chrome on Linux).

I have a .ics file containing details of an event. The ics file was attached to a received email and I downloaded it to my local machine.

I want to add this event to my Outlook calendar. I don't see any "import" or similar options in the Outlook Calendar web client.
How can I import it?

What I've tried:

The "Help" feature in the web client brings no results when searching "ics". When searching "import", it tells you how to manually create an event in your calendar, or how to import a whole calendar (not an event into an existing calendar).

Searching on Google also gives results about importing whole calendars instead of events, and also says irrelevant things like "clicking on the .ics file will import it into your calendar" - this only works with the Windows Outlook executable application, not the web client on Linux.

Comment: What research have you done for this? What have you tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @music2myear I've searched Google and searched on the Help screen of Outlook client itself. In both cases, search results were irrelevant to my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Outlook web client? Did you mean the Outlook on the web(OWA)?

What's the account type of your mailbox? For an Office 365 mailbox, and if you receive the .ics file as an **attachment to an email**, there is a button which is used to add the events from the attached file to the primary calendar in OWA:

[image]

If you have a **local .ics file**, you can upload it to add it to the calender:

- click "Add calendar" in the calendar side bar
- click "Upload from file"
- upload the .ics file

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but no, this is not what I meant - OWA, if I understand correctly, is a Windows application and I'm on Linux. By "Outlook web client" I meant the web page at https://outlook.office.com/calendar/ which I opened in Google Chrome. This doesn't offer me the option to add the linked ICS file to the calendar. I have edited my question to clarify what I meant by "Outlook web client".

Comment: Maybe the button in my edited answer is the thing you want?

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed the answer! I didn't think of clicking "Add calendar" because I didn't want to add a calendar, I just wanted to add an event. The label for that button is misleading.

Comment: OMG, how counter-intuitive can feature naming be? "Add _calendar_", WTF? This is so utterly non-discoverable. Thanks for this answer.