# Is there a way to accept multiple Outlook mails with ics files at once?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, ics

I sometimes receive multiple confirmation emails with ICS attachments. Is there a change to ACCEPT them all at once to add them to the calender.

---

There is "automatically accepting", but this is not what I mean:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/meeting-invites-acceptdecline-multiple-at-a-time/0824b722-05a2-4014-b57f-8813d7ae5a01

Also realized that there are already 2 similar questions:

[Single click to accept meeting invite in Outlook 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/205604/single-click-to-accept-meeting-invite-in-outlook-2010)

https://superuser.com/a/1218860/72397

Outlook web seems to have a one-click function: https://superuser.com/a/1679859/72397

My emails are a bit different from the outlook meeting requests, as they are "normal" emails with an ICS file attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could equally well decline the meetings, so no, Outlook does not have a method to do multiple accepts simultaneously.

Comment: As these are emails by a booking system, primarily I just want to see them in my calender. Accept/Decline is not so important here.

I use Accept to "transfer" them in my calender, if there is a better way to do so, most likely it would be sufficient.

Comment: I have not seen any way to do what you want (very long time user of Outlook). You need to accept / decline individually.